# visual c++ include folders, libraries, etc

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm an engineer, not a strong programmer. I'm writing some simulations using openGL and freeglut. I develop on my computer at home or at school or work so I need to keep everything contained. Typically I've gotten things to work by placing needed libraries in my solution folder and linking to them in the project properties. Any header files I've also put in the solution folder (or subfolder if already defined e.g. GL/freeglut.h). Then in my source files I use a command like `#include "GL/freeglut.h"` with quotes. In my most recent project I'm having problems with another set of headers that deal with hardware that have classes with the same name. It is my understanding that if you keep your headers in separate folders and be careful with namespaces there shouldn't be a problem. I can also configure additional include folders for the project then I use a command like `#include <GL/freeglut.h>`. What is the best way to set all of this up?

Comment: freeglut is C not C++, so doesn't have a namespace. If your other libraries are also C then you'll have problems. Your best bet would probably be to recompile one of them as C++ and wrap its files with a namespace block. You can't do anything (that I'm aware of) after it's been compiled into a library. Standard practice in C is to use a different prefix for each project/library to avoid this situation, but sometimes there are collisions.

Comment: I didn't say freeglut had a namespace, but other headers I'm using do. In other words is it good/bad practice to have folders: bin, include, lib in my project folder, or just dump everything in the same folder? How does this all work?

Comment: Generally you should have a common folder. On UNIX it's often `/usr/*`, on Windows I don't know what the convention is. It makes it much easier to update libraries, since you don't have lots of copies. Also it's usually possible to set your IDE to have include, library, etc. folders which are shared across all projects, so that you don't need to set everything up with each new app. Libraries sometimes have their own conventions too, which complicates things.

Comment: I don't have the benefit of a common folder. I use computers in 3 different places with different sys admin.